# What does Chrome do to speed up page rendering?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've heard Google claim that Chrome uses certain techniques to be faster than other browsers; in particular I heard it has something to do with handling Javascript differently. Can someone explain what techniques Chrome uses to speed up page rendering?

Comment: Why the vote to close? How is this "subjective and argumentative"?!

Comment: where does it says vote to close please?

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to close vote, so you can't see them; see [What is reputation?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) in the FAQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from the source:

http://chrome.blogspot.com/2009/12/technically-speaking-what-makes-google.html (Part I)
http://blog.chromium.org/2010/04/technically-speaking-what-makes-google.html (Part II)